# Umbraco Website Data

Tags: umbraco

I am migrating our Umbraco website to mobile application.

I searched on the Umbraco forums but could not find the documentation for "From where the data is loaded on the website" so that I can manipulate it as per the mobile device.

Are there any documents for this?

Comment: Have you looked into the Umbraco REST framework, or other methods of outputting JSON from your Umbraco backend?

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly you are looking for how the data is presented on the website? Most likely through templates that are attached to your contentnode (look at property tab and there should be a template selected). You can find the template files in the Views directory of your solution or in the Settings tab of the umbraco backend. Another possibility (in case of a SPA) is that api controllers are providing the website with information.